# How does `std::mem::swap` work?

Tags: memory, rust, swap

> Swap the values at two mutable locations of the same type, without deinitialising or copying either one.
>
> ```
> use std::mem;
>
> let x = &mut 5;
> let y = &mut 42;
>
> mem::swap(x, y);
>
> assert_eq!(42, *x);
> assert_eq!(5, *y);
> ```

(From [offical Rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html))

How can two values be swapped without copying? How did the value `42` go from `y` to `x`? This shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I bet you've never heard of the [triple xor trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm), which is a popular trivia in coding interviews.  Not sure if the standard library implements it this way or not though..

Comment: I remember back in the assembly days that doing several XOR statements can swap data without a third memory space to copy to.  I'm not sure that is what "swap" uses however. maybe you can view the assembly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: Yeah already heard of it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function does actually make a copy internally: here is its source extracted from the documentation:

```rust
pub fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        // Give ourselves some scratch space to work with
        let mut t: T = uninitialized();

        // Perform the swap, `&mut` pointers never alias
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*x, &mut t, 1);
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*y, x, 1);
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&t, y, 1);

        // y and t now point to the same thing,
        // but we need to completely forget `t`
        // because it's no longer relevant.
        forget(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Um... doesn't this totally contradict the description: "without [...] copying"? Or do they mean that no value will be duplicated?

Comment: There is a difference between “rust-level copying” (duplicated values, would need to be free'd twice) and implementation level copying. In rust semantics, there are no copies here, the two values just move.

Comment: @Kapichu the "no copy" here mostly means that the type you do the sawp on does not need to be `Clone` or `Copy`, it does not mean that no temporary memory storage is used.

Comment: Note that by the current rules of Rust this code exhibits undefined behavior because it creates a value containing uninitialized data, as well as a reference to such value. Today the same logic would be expressed with `MaybeUninit`, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84c6153af7089e1bc199a3513a1d2874).

Answer (score 11):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31213780/155423) is correct in semantics, but outdated in exact details.

Logically, swapping two values works by reading value A into a temporary location, copying B on top of A, then writing the temporary value back into B. There is a brief period where the same value exists twice in memory. This is why the *implementation* of these functions requires `unsafe` code, as only a human can guarantee that Rust's safety requirements are upheld.

As of Rust 1.43.0, [`mem::swap` is implemented as](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.43.0/src/libcore/mem/mod.rs#L553-L559):

```rust
pub fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    // SAFETY: the raw pointers have been created from safe mutable references satisfying all the
    // constraints on `ptr::swap_nonoverlapping_one`
    unsafe {
        ptr::swap_nonoverlapping_one(x, y);
    }
}
```

`swap_nonoverlapping_one` is private, but [its implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.43.0/src/libcore/ptr/mod.rs#L406-L416) is:

```rust
pub(crate) unsafe fn swap_nonoverlapping_one<T>(x: *mut T, y: *mut T) {
    // For types smaller than the block optimization below,
    // just swap directly to avoid pessimizing codegen.
    if mem::size_of::<T>() < 32 {
        let z = read(x);
        copy_nonoverlapping(y, x, 1);
        write(y, z);
    } else {
        swap_nonoverlapping(x, y, 1);
    }
}
```

You can see the documentation for [`ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html) and [`ptr::swap_nonoverlapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.swap_nonoverlapping.html). The latter is basically a highly-optimized version of copying for larger values.