# How can I write my own swap function in Rust?

Tags: rust, swap

[`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) has the signature:

```
pub fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T)
```

If I  try to implement it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0030e65b650aa81c849d91282187d093)):

```rust
pub fn swap<T>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) {
    let t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

I get an error about the lifetimes of the two parameters:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/lib.rs:4:9
  |
1 | pub fn swap<T>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) {
  |                   ------     ------
  |                   |
  |                   these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
...
4 |     b = t;
  |         ^ ...but data from `a` flows into `b` here

error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
1 | pub fn swap<T>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) {
  |                   ------     ------ these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
2 |     let t = a;
3 |     a = b;
  |         ^ ...but data from `b` flows into `a` here
```

If I change the signature to:

```rust
pub fn swap_lt<'t, T>(mut a: &'t T, mut b: &'t T)
```

It compiles, but I get a warning which seems to mean that we're just swapping temporary copies:

```
warning: value assigned to `a` is never read
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     a = b;
  |     ^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_assignments)]` on by default
  = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?

warning: value assigned to `b` is never read
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     b = t;
  |     ^
  |
  = help: maybe it is overwritten before being read?
```

Comment: See also [How does `std::mem::swap` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31213286/155423)

Answer (score 6):

Your code is not operating on temporary copies. It just swaps the references that were passed in, which does not have any effect on the values they are pointing to. This also explains why the compiler wants the lifetimes to match – reference `x` is pointing to the value reference `y` pointed to before and vice versa, which is only possible if the two references have the same lifetime.

When swapping the actual values, a different problem occurs. You first need to move one of the values to a temporary variable. However, since `T` is not `Copy`, you can't move a value out from behind a reference, since this would leave the reference invalid, which is not allowed in Rust. If you allow `T: Default`, you could replace the value with its default temporarily. However, if you want to implement the function for the general case, you need to resort to unsafe code. One way of doing so is using the `std::ptr::read()` and `std::ptr::write()` functions to read and write data from raw pointers:

```
fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        let z = read(x);
        write(x, read(y));
        write(y, z);
    }
}
```

This code is trickier than it looks. The `read()` function returns a copy of the value without invalidating the original value, so we end up with the same non-`Copy` value being present in two places. We need to take care that we don't drop any of the values, which happens implicitly in many cases. For example, this implementation is wrong, since it implicitly drops the value `x` is initially pointing to

```
fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        let z = read(x);
        *x = read(y);     // Wrong – drops the original value x is pointing to
        write(y, z);
    }
}
```

The actual implementation of `swap()` in the standard library uses a few optimizations:

- It makes use of the `std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping()` function instead of `write(x, read(y))`, which is implemented as a compiler intrinsic. The Rust compiler delegates this to LLVM to make sure the generated code is as efficient as possible for the target platform. Our code actually uses temporary storage for *both* `x` and `y`. Using `copy_nonoverlapping()`, temporary storage is only needed for one of the variables.
- Values of size 32 or larger are swapped in blocks, so only 32 bytes of temporary storage are needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you, for the sake of an exercise, don't want to use `core::mem::swap` or say `core::ptr::swap`, you could implement it as such:

```rust
pub fn swap<T>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        let t = core::ptr::read(a);
        core::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(b, a, 1);
        core::ptr::write(b, t);
    }
}
```

Doing it using strictly safe code is not possible without having something like `T: Default`.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have covered unsafe implementations of `swap()`. A safe implementation is possible as well, but it requires additional constraints on `T`. For example:

```
pub fn swap<T: Default>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    let t = std::mem::take(x);
    *x = std::mem::take(y);
    *y = t;
}
```

Here `T: Default` is required by [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), which moves the value out of an `&mut T` reference, and leaves `T::default()` as replacement. A replacement is needed because the value behind the reference can and will be used again, so it must be in a valid state. For example, to move the value out of `*x`, we need to leave a well-defined value in `*x` because we will assign to `*x` in the subsequent line. The assignment, unaware of the previous operation, expects a valid value on the left-hand side, in order to destroy it. Leaving the old value untouched in `*x` would result in use-after-free and ultimately a double-free.

Another option is to require `Clone`:

```
pub fn swap<T: Clone>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    let t = x.clone();
    *x = y.clone();
    *y = t;
}
```

For standard library containers this variant will be less efficient because `T::clone()` will perform a deep copy of the container, whereas `T::default()` will create an empty container without performing an allocation.

Implementing `swap()` without additional constraint on `T` requires unsafe code, as shown in other answers.